# postfix test and configuration problem

Tags: linux, postfix

I installed postfix using >sudo yum install postfix postfix-mysql. I'm 
newbie to mail systems, but I have one AMAZON EC2 instance with a 
public DNS. I used the public DNS in most cases, when I configured the 
file main.cf. The public DNS I have is from amazon and it is a long 
string(ec2-123-34-234-677.....amazon.com).

```
// I configured this on main.cf. I replaced example.com with 
ec2-123-.......amazon.com 
myhostname = mail.example.com 
mydomain = example.com 
myorigin = $mydomain 
mydestination = example.com, $transport_maps 
local_recipient_maps = $alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps 
unix:passwd.byname 
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

How do I test postfix? I just want it to send emails for my web 
application. I tried to test it with `>telnet localhost 25` after I typed in SSH `>sudo postfix start`. but I 
recieve the message that telnet command can not be found. 
I also use the Amazon linux distribution if you want to know. I use it 
because it is free.

What have I done wrong? Are there anymore configurations required pls help!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing telnet with:

```
sudo yum install telnet
```

And then you can test it with telnet to port 25.

But note that sending emails from Amazon EC2 servers is not a great idea, as a lot of people have Amazon's entire IP range blacklisted in their spam filters.

Comment: Hi Scott! Is it ok to use Amazon SES? I have done some minor research and figured out that they are cheapiest